# Template overloads with array types: Force char array to use string_view

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a `print()` template method overloaded to handle different types. There are three categories I'm concerned with:

- Array types of scalar values excluding literal strings (e.g. `unsigned foo[5]`)
- String literals (e.g. `"Hello World"`)
- String types (`char const*` and `std::string`)

The first item should be handled differently than strings (the last 2 points). Here is some code I've written to try to distinguish between them ([LIVE SAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u8mpFpDQkPbBpMNE)):

```cpp
template<typename Container, typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod_v<T> && !std::is_pointer_v<T> && !std::is_array_v<T>, int> = 0>
void print(T const&)
{
    std::cout << "Generic Value\n";
}

template<typename Container, typename Array, std::size_t Size>
void print(Array const (&)[Size])
{
    std::cout << "Array\n";
}

template<typename Container>
void print(std::string_view)
{
    std::cout << "String View\n";
}

int main()
{
    { // GOOD: Uses string_view
        char const* value = "Hello";
        print<int>(value);
    }
    { // GOOD: Uses string_view
        std::string value = "value";
        print<int>(value);
    }
    { // GOOD: Uses array overload
        unsigned value[] = {1, 2, 3};
        print<int>(value);
    }
    { // BAD: Should use the string_view overload
        print<int>("Hello");
    }
}
```

The output I get:

```
String View
String View
Array
Array
```

Note the case labeled `BAD`. I expect this to be handled by `string_view`, but because it's technically an array, it doesn't. I suppose I could solve this by doing an `enable_if` with `is_same` to check for (and exclude) `char` types for the `Array` parameter, but that seems a bit hairy.

Is there a more manageable way to generically program for these types? Essentially I want to handle strings as strings (mostly because of the null terminator), and non-strings as raw bytes of data.

Some context / notes:

The example uses a `Container` template argument that is pointless. This is just to force all the functions to be templates. In my real code this is a meaningful template argument (actually refers to a STL container that the value passed gets written into as a series of bytes). Also the `print` method in my real code is actually an overloaded `<<` operator. The whole point of my real code is to write various types as binary data to a container (like iostreams for binary data). I handle certain types in special ways (e.g. strings ignore null terminators), which is why I've got so many overloads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array template is a better match for `char[]` types, since the `string_view` version involves a user-defined conversion.

You can either disable the array version for `char[]` types with SFINAE:

```
template<typename Container, typename Array, std::size_t Size,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Array, char>, int> = 0>
void print(Array const (&)[Size])
{
    std::cout << "Array\n";
}
```

Or implement an additional proxy overload:

```
template<typename Container, std::size_t Size>
void print(char const (&s)[Size])
{
    print<Container>(std::string_view(s));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since a string literal is an lvalue `const char[N]`, there is no way for it to pick `std::string_view` over `Array const(&)[Size]`. You would have to disable the array overload for char:

```cpp
template<typename Container, typename Array, std::size_t Size>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Array, char>> print(Array const (&)[Size])
```

But this probably isn't the best solution, as you can't know if it is null terminated (There is no way to tell if a `const char` array is a string literal or an array of bytes). e.g., the following is UB:

```
char value[] = { 1 };  // Not null terminated
print<int>(value);  // Constructing a string_view from non-null terminated array
```

You would probably want a [string view literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv), so you won't need to worry about the array overload being used:

```cpp
using namespace std::literals;
print<int>("Hello"sv);
```